# Recursive ui router nested views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a file viewer and I want to nest the subdirectories. I am using ui-router and I want each subdirectory to have its own URL and state.

Say I have the following structure:

```
Root
  |__Folder
  |__Folder
     |__SubFolder
        |__SubSubFolder
```

I want my routes to be:

```
files/:folderID/:SubFolderID/:SubSubFolderID
```

And I would like to do that recursively as opposed to creating a new state for each subdirectory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest, do it with **one state** and **one param** - `folderPath`. Because `ui-router` should have all the states defined soon enough, to support url routing. All these unique folderPath could differ, could be dynamic - in the runtime, in app life time.

> Dynamic state definition is always an issue *(if states are defined in app.run() it could happen that user comes to url which is not defined yet - `otherwise` is used... bad)*

**Dynamic `url` parameter** - will work always. We just have to parse it in controller and decide next steps. Here is a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/uOFXYeEneIIEmsREa5Ci?p=preview).

The state and its param could be like this

```
.state('files', {
      url: '/files/{folderPath:[a-zA-Z0-9/]*}',
      templateUrl: 'tpl.files.html',
      controller: 'FileCtrl'
    });
```

Later we can dynamically generate navigation  (links) like this:

```
<a href="#/files/Folder1">
<a href="#/files/Folder1/SubFolder1/">
<a href="#/files/Folder1/SubFolder1/SubFolderA">
<a href="#/files/Folder1/SubFolder1/SubFolderB">
<a href="#/files/Folder1/SubFolder2/SubFolderX">
```

check that in this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/uOFXYeEneIIEmsREa5Ci?p=preview)

Comment: That's perfect. It's not 100% handled but the router, but it can be worked with :)