# Angular UI-Router parsing URL that contains slashes as part of state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a nested a state that is associated with a file path within a directory. That is, the url for the view is something like `/workspace/path/to/my/file.txt`. Right now, simply using `/:path` does not work. How can ui-router be configured to accept slashes in the middle of a route?

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('workspace.file', {
        url: '/:path',
        parent: 'workspace',
        views: {
          fileTabs: {
            templateUrl: 'app/workspace/workspace.file/file.html',
          }
        },
        controller: 'WorkspaceFileCtrl'
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to match using a regex:

```
 url: '/{path:.*}'
```

Or their shortcut catchall syntax:

```
url: '/*path'
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar Q & A: - [Recursive ui router nested views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732164/)

So, we can use more precise regex def:

```
.state('workspace.file', {
      url: '/files/{folderPath:[a-zA-Z0-9/.]*}',
      templateUrl: 'tpl.files.html',
      controller: 'FileCtrl'
    });
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3ptsQY6v0mzt3JvoITHz?p=preview) with an example