# Angular UI-Router more Optional Parameters in one State

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

How can I allow optional parameters to my routes without using a query string and only using one route name?  I am currently specifying each route FIVE TIMES to allow for any combination of parts:

**All parts must be optional.  Route must resolve any variation.**

```
.state("login", { url: "/login", templateUrl: "login.html", params: { a: null, b: null, c: null, d: null } })
.state("loginA", { url: "/login/:a", templateUrl: "login.html", params: { b: null, c: null, d: null } })
.state("loginAB", { url: "/login/:a/:b", templateUrl: "login.html", params: { c: null, d: null } })
.state("loginABC", { url: "/login/:a/:b/:c", templateUrl: "login.html", params: { d: null } })
.state("loginABCD", { url: "/login/:a/:b/:c/:d", templateUrl: "login.html" })
```

There MUST be an easier / cleaner / less ugly way.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Short answer....

```
.state('login', {
    url: '/login/:a/:b/:c/:d',
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    params: {
        a: { squash: true, value: null },
        b: { squash: true, value: null },
        c: { squash: true, value: null },
        d: { squash: true, value: null },
    }
})
```

Answer (score 27):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g9uQXMuE8bXRULfyESAs?p=preview)

Solution here could be of two types. The first is really very dynamic. The second is working as needed, a bit more rigid, but profiting from `UI-Router` built-in features.

#### I. Dynamic approach

Let's observe the first, which is interesting *(but maybe too much complicated in our scenario)*. It is very similar to this Q & A

[Recursive ui router nested views](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25732164/1679310)

We try to solve the *url* which contains unknown amount of folders*(directories)* names:

```
<a href="#/files/Folder1">
<a href="#/files/Folder1/SubFolder1/">
<a href="#/files/Folder1/SubFolder1/SubFolderA">
```

State could be define like this:

```
.state('files', {
  url: '/files/{folderPath:[a-zA-Z0-9/]*}',
  templateUrl: 'tpl.files.html',
  ...
```

And that will lead to one param **`folderPath`** with the complete folder path.

In case we would like to solve our scenario *(handle exactly three params)* we could extend stuff like this

Controller for File handling:

```
.controller('FileCtrl', function($scope, a, b, c) {
    $scope.paramA = a; 
    $scope.paramB = b; 
    $scope.paramC = c; 
})
```

State definition using resolver:

```
// helper method
var findParams = function($stateParams, position) {
   var parts = $stateParams.folderPath.split('/')
   var result = parts.length >= position ? parts[position] : null;
   return result;
  }

...

// state calls resolver to parse params and pass them into controller
.state('files', {
    url: '/files/{folderPath:[a-zA-Z0-9/]*}',
    templateUrl: 'tpl.files.html',
    controller: 'FileCtrl',
    resolve: {
        a : ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {return findParams($stateParams, 0)}],
        b : ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {return findParams($stateParams, 1)}],
        c : ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {return findParams($stateParams, 2)}],
    }
 })
```

#### II. UI-Router built-in feature `params : {}`

The second scenario, is in fact very very simple. It uses `UI-Router` built in feature: `params : {}`. Check its documentation here:

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider

This would be our state definition:

```
.state('login', {
    url: '/login/:a/:b/:c',
    templateUrl: 'tpl.login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    params: {
        a: {squash: true, value: null},
        b: {squash: true, value: null},
        c: {squash: true, value: null},
    }
})
```

And all these links will work as well:

```
<a href="#/login">
<a href="#/login/ValueA">
<a href="#/login/ValueA/ValueB">
<a href="#/login/ValueA/ValueB/ValueC">
```

And what was the trick:

> **`squash`** - *`{bool|string=}`*: squash configures how a default parameter value is represented in the URL when the current parameter value is the same as the default value. If squash is not set, it uses the configured default squash policy.

Check it in [action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/g9uQXMuE8bXRULfyESAs?p=preview)

Comment: @pootzko Great to see that, thanks a lot for response ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router

Answer (score 3):

Another simple way to do this is to just set a default value for the parameter, like this:

```
params: {
  thing1: ""
}
```

According to the Angular [UI Router docs](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/1.0.0/interfaces/params.paramdeclaration.html#value), setting a default value automatically makes the parameter optional.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass optional parameters using [ui-sref](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref). You can then access them in your controller using the $stateParams service. Parameters that don't get passed would just remain null.

```
.state("loginABCD", 
  { url: "/login/:a/:b/:c/:d",
    templateUrl: "login.html"
    controller: function($stateParams) {
      console.log($stateParams.a + $stateParams.b);
      }
  })
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this format prevents other variations from resolving.  For example, "/login" or "/login/123" will not resolve to this state.