# Dynamic optional ui.router $stateParams?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to have dynamic ui.router `$stateParams` parameters?  IF a user supplies parameters on the route, I simply want to address them by name or ordinal position.  However, I don't want to define them on every single state.

Something like this...

```
.state('selector', {
    url: '/select/:brandId/:userId/:appId/:appVerId/:featureId/:dialogId/:controlId/:token',
    template: null,
    controller: 'Selector',
    params: {
        brandId     : { squash: true, value: null },
        userId      : { squash: true, value: null },
        appId       : { squash: true, value: null },
        appVerId    : { squash: true, value: null },
        featureId   : { squash: true, value: null },
        dialogId    : { squash: true, value: null },
        controlId   : { squash: true, value: null },
        token       : { squash: true, value: null }
    }
})
```

... or this ...

```
.state('selector', {
    url: '/select/:a/:b/:c/:d/:e/:f/:g/:h',
    template: null,
    controller: 'Selector',
    params: {
        a : { squash: true, value: null },
        b : { squash: true, value: null },
        c : { squash: true, value: null },
        d : { squash: true, value: null },
        e : { squash: true, value: null },
        f : { squash: true, value: null },
        g : { squash: true, value: null },
        h : { squash: true, value: null }
    }
})
```

I would like to access them by name or with the ordinal position...

```
var a = $stateParams.a; // or
var b = $stateParams[1];
```

This would allow the following URLs to be valid:

```
http://adsf.com/selector  
http://adsf.com/selector/////217H3  
http://adsf.com/selector/23AD/12D///217H3
```

Comment: valid by whose definition? have never seen url's like that before. Why can't you use query params?

Comment: Have you seen this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30230421/1679310 to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already answered this **for you** on another thread **five months** prior to you asking this one...

[Angular UI-Router more Optional Parameters in one State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225424/angular-ui-router-more-optional-parameters-in-one-state/30230421#30230421)

Short answer....

```
.state('login', {
    url: '/login/:a/:b/:c/:d',
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    params: {
        a: { squash: true, value: null },
        b: { squash: true, value: null },
        c: { squash: true, value: null },
        d: { squash: true, value: null },
    }
})
```