# Optional parameter/path on ui router state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angular-ui-router

Trying to figure out how to have a completely optional parameter for a state so that having a query string on the URL of what otherwise would be the home state(/) will actually route to the search state. Not sure if Regex here is even the proper approach.

**URL -> State mapping**

- url `/` should go to state `home`
- url `/?search=` should go to state `search`
- url `/?search=foo` should go to state `search`
- url `/:slug/` should go to state `search`
- url `/:slug/?search=foo` should go to state `search`

**Home State**

```
name: 'home',
url: '/',
component: 'appHome',
```

**Search State**

```
name: 'search',
url: '/{slug: [.*]?}?search=',
component: 'appCategory',
params: {
    slug: { dynamic: true },
    search: { dynamic: true },
},
```

Comment: Check this out! https://stackoverflow.com/a/30230421/2079271