# Order of query params should not matter for Angular UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on a AngularJS project v1.5.8, which is using angular-ui-router.
The routes are setup something like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('demoapp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('landing', {
      url: '/?paramOne&paramTwo&paramThree',
      template: '<h3>Landing Page with params.</h3>',
    })
    .state('landing.pageA', {
      url: '',
      template: '<h3>Landing Page A!</h3>',
    })
    .state('landing.pageB', {
      url: '',
      template: '<h3>Landing Page B!</h3>',
    })
    .state('error', {
      url: '/error',
      template: '<h3>Error Page!</h3>',
    });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

For the `landing` states, the params are not always passed in the order specified.
And sometimes, one or more of the params is omitted. A different service redirect to this app and passes the query params.

- Is there a way to make to make some or all of the params optional?
- Require only the first one, and it should not matter if the rest are passed?
- Make the order they are being passed not matter? But, still render the template specified under state `landing`.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225424/angular-ui-router-more-optional-parameters-in-one-state , checkout..

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make to make some or all of the params optional?

Yes.

From the Docs:

> ## Using Parameters without Specifying Them in State URLs
>
> You still can specify what parameters to receive even though the parameters don't appear in the url. You need to add a new field params in the state and create links as specified in Using Parameters in Links
>
> For example, you have the state.
>
> ```
> .state('contacts', {
>         url: "/contacts",
>         params: {
>             param1: null
>         },
>         templateUrl: 'contacts.html'
>     })
> ```
>
> The link you create is
>
> ```
> <a ui-sref="contacts({param1: value1})">View Contacts</a>
> ```

For more information, see

- [Angular-UI-Router Wiki - URL Routing](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#using-parameters-without-specifying-them-in-state-urls)

Comment: This would work when changing states from html like above. But it does not work when the params are passed on the url.