# Nested, dynamic paths in Angularjs UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, state, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular app, which is a dashboard style app that allows users to drill down n number of levels. I'm trying to set up dynamic paths, which append a new dashboard id every time a user drills down. So for example, the root dashboard will look like this:

```
/reporting/dashboard/root
```

Then if a user drills down 4 times, it may look something like this:

```
/reporting/dashboard/root/dashboard1/dashboard2/dashboard3/dashboard4
```

I've tried using a regex pattern in my state config to no avail. I can't figure out how to append the path when calling `$state.go()`.

```
state: 'dashboard',
    config: {
              url:"/reporting/dashboard/{path:.*}",
              templateUrl: function(params) {
                  var path = params.path.split('/').reverse(),
                  var guid = path[0];
                  params.guid = guid;
                  return 'views/dashboard/dashboard.html';
              },
              controller:'DashboardController'
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Maybe there is a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Couldn't you just make Level a parameter such that /reporting/dashboard?level=1&page=users ?

Answer (score 2):

The way I would suggest to go is in detail described here:

- [Recursive ui router nested views](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25732164/1679310) and
- [Angular UI-Router more Optional Parameters in one State](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30230421/1679310)

we would need an regex like this `*{myPath:[a-zA-Z0-9/]*}*`:

```
state: 'dashboard',
    config: {
              url:"/reporting/dashboard/{myPath:[a-zA-Z0-9/]*}",
              templateUrl: function(params) {
                  var path = params.path.split('/').reverse(),
                  var guid = path[0];
                  params.guid = guid;
                  return 'views/dashboard/dashboard.html';
              },
              controller:'DashboardController'
    }
```

And as the plunker [from above example shows](http://plnkr.co/edit/uOFXYeEneIIEmsREa5Ci?p=preview) *(it is about folder and files)* - we can use any kind of links:

```
<a href="#/reporting/dashboard/root/dashboard1">
<a href="#/reporting/dashboard/root/dashboard1/dashboard2">
<a href="#/reporting/dashboard/root/dashboard1/dashboard2/dashboard3">
<a href="#/reporting/dashboard/root/dashboard1/dashboard2/dashboard3/dashboard4">
```

and the params will be `myPath = 'root/dashboard1/dashboard2/dashboard3/dashboard4'` for the last state, so even this would work:

```
<a ui-sref="dashboard({myPath: 'root/dashboard1/dashboard2/dashboard3/dashboard4'})">
```